# Disappearing FormClosing/FormClosed events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, events

Following code snippet may look weird, but it is a very simple method to reproduce the problem of a complicated interaction with a different application.

The example application has two forms, both forms register FormClosing and FormClosed events, just doing a Debug.WriteLine there.

The Main function does:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

When I close Form2, I receive the events as expected. When I close Form1, the application exits and Form2 gets closed too. But: the events of Form2 do not occur.

I overrode the WndProc of Form2. When I close Form2, I receive

```
15.10.2012 10:25:04 WndProc - WM_CLOSE
15.10.2012 10:25:04 OnClosing
15.10.2012 10:25:04 Form2_FormClosing
15.10.2012 10:25:04 OnClosed
15.10.2012 10:25:04 Form2_FormClosed
...
15.10.2012 10:25:04 WndProc - WM_DESTROY
...
15.10.2012 10:25:04 WndProc - WM_NCDESTROY
```

When I close Form1, Form2 does not receive a WM_CLOSE. But WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY are received.

Edit:
A different way of getting this strange behavior is as follows:
The project has three forms, Form1 and Form2 have each a button for opening the next form. In the button click event of form2, do:

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.Parent = null;
frm3.Show(null);
```

Again, register event handlers as described above. When closing form2, the application stays running (form1 is still shown), but also form3 gets closed, and no WM_CLOSE event received. Note that I already set both Parent and Owner of the form to null.

What is the reason for that strange behavior?

Answer (score 3):

`WM_CLOSE` message is sent to have an option of canceling closing. See this flowchart:

[image]

So, there is no need in this message, when window is about to be destroyed anyway. This is behavior by design. When you are closing main form of application, `Application.ThreadExit` method is called. It described as:

> Exits the message loop on the current thread and closes all windows on
>   the thread.

If you want all opened forms to receive `WM_CLOSE` message, you need to use `Application.Exit` instead:

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes
>   all application windows after the messages have been processed.

Thus simply subscribe to `Form1_FormClosing` event and inform all opened windows about closing:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. Now I understand why  do not get the message in this example.

Comment: But the setting where we discovered the problem first is far more complicated. ThirdParty defined a C++ interface. We implement that in a mixed-mode (unmanaged/managed) dll. When ThirdParty calls the StartUp method, we create a window for communication (and make the desktop to its owner).
And when ThirdParty closes the window from where our system was loaded, also our window disappears - without the events. But our system, stays loaded (i.e. they do not unload the Application Domain). Now we have to find out which other ways exist to close a window without getting the events.

Comment: You can override `WndProc` on your `Form2`, and process `WM_DESTROY` message by calling `Close()` method. It will dispose form and it's resources.